# Execute batch file + call Visual Studio Command Prompt

Tags: tfs, batch-file, command-prompt

I have a batchfile ( see code below ).
Because the tf command must be executed in the Visual Studio command prompt.
I call the visual studio command.

But then the batch file stops executing.
Somebody have an idea?

```
        REM @echo off
        REM ... Change the path below. This is the path where the code will be downloaded!
        REM Z:
        REM cd Backup_TFS_Preview
        call %comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86

        REM ... Navigate to folder
        Z:
        cd Backup_TFS_Preview

        REM ... Makes folder with date today
        mkdir %Date:~-10,2%-%Date:~-7,2%-%Date:~-4,4%

        REM ... Navigate to folder
        cd %Date:~-10,2%-%Date:~-7,2%-%Date:~-4,4%

        REM ... Add workspace for the folder with date of today
        tf workspace /new %Date:~-10,2%-%Date:~-7,2%-%Date:~-4,4% /noprompt

        REM ... Get all items from TFS
        tf get /recursive /all /noprompt

        REM ... Navigate to folder
        cd ..

        REM ... Zip the folder
        C:\TFS_Backup_Scripts\7z.exe a %Date:~-10,2%-%Date:~-7,2%-%Date:~-4,4%.zip %Date:~-10,2%-%Date:~-7,2%-%Date:~-4,4%\

        REM ... Remove folder
        rmdir %Date:~-10,2%-%Date:~-7,2%-%Date:~-4,4%\ /s /q

        REM ... Delete workspace
        tf workspace /delete %Date:~-10,2%-%Date:~-7,2%-%Date:~-4,4% /noprompt

        REM ... Navigate to folder
        cd ..
        cd ..

        REM ... Delete zip files that are older then 10 days 
        forfiles -p "Z:\Backup_TFS_Preview" -s -m *.* -d -10 -c "cmd /c del /q @path"
```

Comment: It stops after the call ..... line.

Comment: @Sven iam trying to do the exact same thing actually, by automating it from Jenkins and got that error message that tf is not a recognized command. - you care to share your working solution with the absolute path if you still have it? thanks

Comment: @uniXVanXcel I don't use that stuff anymore. So I don't have any working solution anymore. Sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in another way. I used the full path of the tf.exe. And it works in the command prompt.

The call answer doens't worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

%comspec% /k runs *another* command prompt, and then keeps cmd.exe around. Until that cmd.exe returns, your batch file won't continue.

Even if you replace /k with /c (which doesn't keep cmd.exe around), it won't work, because the environment variables from the new command prompt aren't preserved in this one.

You simply need:

```
call %VS100COMNTOOLS%\vsvars32.bat
```

Or

```
call %VS100COMNTOOLS%\..\..\VC\vcvarsall.bat x86
```

Comment: Doesn't help me. It runs the whole script but it doesn't use the Visual Studio command prompt. Because tf is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Answer (score 0):

what happens when you execute the call from a cmd prompt?

also note the exit code (0 or 1) for vcvars32.bat (which is called by vcvarsall.bat) so run: Echo %errorlevel%
after you run vcvarsall.bat. if it is zero the command completed successfully.

and you might try and remove the dbl "" like this:
call %comspec% /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
that could break the cmd statement up into bad pararameters due to the spaces not being escaped

maybe test for the %errorlevel% right after the call line

last resort, change the /k to /c in the call statement.

post results